# SSAS MDX Median with time series

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, median, mdx-query

I am trying to calculate a median on timeseries monitoring data.

The OLAP cube has a date dimension (lowest level is date) and a seperate time dimension. (lowest level is minute)

I've found that it calculates correctly for a given day, but it rolls up the values for the month. (it should be ~1.55 for the month)

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Medianx] AS MEDIAN([Time].[Time Key].MEMBERS , [Measures].[Total of Values])      

SELECT NON EMPTY {
[Measures].[Count of Values], 
[Measures].[Minimum Value], 
[Measures].[Maximum Value], 
[Measures].[Total of Values], 
[Measures].[Medianx]
} ON COLUMNS,  

NON EMPTY ( [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS )  ON ROWS 

FROM [Environmental Data]
```

Gives this:

[image]

The Median for the Month can't be higher than median of the 5 individual days.

How do I get OLAP to calculate the Median correctly across the time range selected when rolling up? (e.g by Day *and* Month *and* Year)

Could it be caused by having seperate date and time dimensions?

Edit: I've found that if I just a degereate dimension wihc has a 1:1 relationship with the fact. It calcalates correctly for the month, but is really slow. (2min30sec for 1429 rows of data)

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Medianx] AS MEDIAN([Data Attributes].[DETL Key].MEMBERS, [Measures].[Total of Values])
```

However, if I try to query grouping by day it never finishes the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I could use the DESCENDANTS function to drill down through both the Date & Time dimensions to get to an average aggregate with a granularity of 1 minute per day.

```
MEDIAN(NonEmptyCrossJoin(DESCENDANTS([Date].[Calendar Date].CurrentMember, , LEAVES), DESCENDANTS([Time].[Time Key].CurrentMember, , LEAVES)), [Measures].[Average Value])
```

Testing found than given the nature of the data an average per minute gave a reliable median. Because it's calculated on aggregates rather than raw data it runs very quickly.

I don't really understand why, but it now calculates correctly for the day, month and year.

Warning: If I select 5 days of the month i will get the correct median for each day, and I will get the correct median for the **entire** month. (Rather than the median of the 5 days selected).